TypeError: source must be an AudioSource not FFmpegOpusAudio
async def play(ctx, *, link):
    try:
        voice_client = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
        voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    if 1==1:
        if youtube_base_url not in link:
            query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
                'search_query': link
            })

            content = urllib.request.urlopen(
                youtube_results_url + query_string
            )

            search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{11})', content.read().decode())

            link = youtube_watch_url + search_results[0]

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(link, download=False))

        song = data['url']
        player = discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options)

        voice_clients[ctx.guild.id].play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(play_next(ctx), bot.loop))

ffmpeg installed and added in PATH
ffmpeg lib for python added
I tried other variations of ffmpeg(like FFmpegPCMAudio) but this didn't solve the problem. I also tried to just copy-paste(Someone else's code that performs the same functions), which also did not give anything. I think the problem is not in the code.
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Saliceterik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\core.py", line 173, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saliceterik\Desktop\snackerbot\launch_serviceTyan_s-upd.py", line 122, in play
    voice_clients[ctx.guild.id].play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(play_next(ctx), bot.loop))    
  File "c:\Users\Saliceterik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\voice_client.py", line 583, in play
    raise TypeError(f"source must be an AudioSource not {source.__class__.__name__}")
TypeError: source must be an AudioSource not FFmpegOpusAudio```


Hey man, this is probably your first time on this forum, but we'll need much more info in order to help. For example what link you're accessing would be incredibly helpful. In order to get good help, read the following question and ask your question again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@Canbach I understand that the title is incorrect, but I can't explain this error, because I can't even imagine what the reason for it is also my English is terrible

Problem solved: do not use disnake and discord.py together
